# Using DCEVM with weblogic 12 and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weblogic12c, dcevm

I have dynamic web project which is deployed as part of EAR on weblogic server. I am using eclipse IDE. I have used jar available on http://dcevm.github.io/ to configure DCEVM as alternated JVM for JDk1.7.0_45. After starting my server and publishing my application, if I make changes to java files(add new methods, rename methods) I don't see the change. I still see the error in eclipse as "Hot code replace failed.
Am I missing any step/setting? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should have some agent that supports weblogic. https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent